# How to remove the commas after conversion to CSV from excel ?

Tags: excel, csv

My macro works perfectly but there are a million commas I do not want

```
Sub CSVwithFormatting()

Dim fDir As String
Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim fPath As String
Dim sPath As String
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

fPath = "path"
sPath = "path"
fDir = Dir(fPath)


Do While (fDir <> "")

If Right(fDir, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsx" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsb" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
On Error Resume Next
Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fDir)
csvWb = wB.Name
dd = Split(csvWb, ".")

wB.ActiveSheet.Open

Dim i As Integer

i = 0

Do While InStr((Range("A1").Value), "/") = 0 And InStr((Range("M1").Value), "/") = 0 And (i < 10)

    Range("1:1").Delete

    i = i + 1

Loop

Windows("Header template.xls").Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy

    wB.ActiveSheet.Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    If Range("e2").NumberFormat = "General" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    End If

    If Range("b4").Value > Range("c4").Value And Range("b6").Value > Range("c6") Then
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If





wB.ActiveSheet.SaveAs sPath & dd(0) & ".csv", xlCSV

wB.Close False
Set wB = Nothing
End If
fDir = Dir
On Error GoTo 0

Loop

End Sub
```

I have to do a lot of formatting in my code before converting to csv, and then after several trimming processes, the excels converted by but there are a lot commas

Comment: open the notepad. replace the commas by the desired character.

Comment: what is your desired output? Some sort of delimiter should exist in any CSV file.

Comment: replace with ''(blank) will give the same problem when loading to sql server, 1 million extra rows